# Not all Code Paths return a Value Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this piece of code in a class (DataBase) and I'm getting

> Not all Paths return a Value.

Any help will be really appreciated.

```
public static DataSet DELETE_PDT(String rowid)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DELETE_PDT", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rowid;

    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WMS"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error while deleting record. Please contact your System Administrator", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should have a `return value` because you have declared it to return `Dataset`.

example,

```
return new Dataset();
```

if you don't want to see the error message, change

```
public static DataSet DELETE_PDT(String rowid)
{
   // statements
}
```

to

```
public static void DELETE_PDT(String rowid)
{
   // statements
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

based on your comments, I'll modifed it to return a string value again.

```
public static string DELETE_PDT(String rowid)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WMS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DELETE_PDT", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rowid;
            try
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "Record has been deleted";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error while deleting record. Please contact your System Administrator";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: John question, how can I call this method from my main code now? This is what I had before 'DataBase.DELETE_PDT(rowid);'

Comment: @jorame the same. you need to specify the class name since the method is static. `DataBase.DELETE_PDT(rowid);`

Comment: I think I figure out. I was using a HiddenField as the rowid. Let me try

Comment: John question, I'm returning a message from the sp_DELETE_PDT. How can I assign this to a Label in my main code. I have this Message.Text = DataBase.DELETE_PDT()

Comment: @jorame before i will answer the question, i need to ask this first. what do you want to assign? the number of records affected or what? :D

Comment: Is just a confirmation message stating that the record has been deleted successfully. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ah ok, so you need to change again the `void` to string. after this line: `con.Close();`, add this, `return "Record has been deleted.";`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17041/discussion-between-john-woo-and-jorame)

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your method to return a `DataSet`... yet you return nothing. So... you need to return an instance of `DataSet` or change your method signature.

Comment: What can I change it to? Thanks

Comment: @jorame: Change the return type to `void`, i.e., return nothing, or actually return a `DataSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared that the method should return a `DataSet`, but it doesn't return anything (which is logical for what the method does). Change the signature to:

```
public static void DELETE_PDT(String rowid)
```

---

Side note: To avoid having an exception leaving an unclosed connection, you can use `using`. It ensures that the command and the connection are always disposed whatever happens:

```
public static void DELETE_PDT(String rowid) {
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()) {
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WMS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DELETE_PDT", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rowid;
      try {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Error while deleting record. Please contact your System Administrator", ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code; try this:

```
public static void DELETE_PDT(String rowid) {
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()) {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WMS"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DELETE_PDT", con)) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rowid;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error while deleting record. Please contact your System Administrator", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and i tht re-factoring would be employing `using` :)